# Define Stormpath API ID and Secret in code instead of file?

Tags: java, authentication, stormpath

This is for a Minecraft plugin.

Stormpath requires you to store your apiKeys.properties file in your home directory, I am looking for a way to define the keys in my config file instead. For example:

```
stormpath:
  application_name: APPLICATION_NAME
  api_key_id: KEY_ID
  api_key_secret: SECRET_KEY
```

There's a section of my YML config file, I would like to use something like this to authenticate with Stormpath instead of having the file in a hidden directory. Is there any way of doing this within java? I know you are able to set environment variables with the keys in but I'm not sure what the best of doing this would be where I could still let the user enter their keys inside the config file.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "Stormpath requires you to"? This is entirely up to how the Stormpath client code in your application is written.

Comment: I guess so, I'm just trying to get the id and secret to be defined in the config.yml instead of the default way which is having apiKey.properties in your home directory (in .stormpath/).

This means that if the plugin is ever distributed, anyone who wants to use it can just enter those details in the config, because some hosts might not let you add that file into that directory.

Comment: Note that you really shouldn't be putting this sort of thing into source control--instead, use the Spring Boot environment bindings.

Comment: @chrylis The config.yml is generated when the user runs the plugin for the first time, it will contain some placeholder information until they enter their own information to link to their stormpath application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can store the Stormpath API key and secret in a YAML file. The configuration path is `stormpath.client.apiKey.[id/secret]` according to the [documentation](https://docs.stormpath.com/java/spring-boot-web/config.html#api-key).

This means that your `stormpath.yaml` file should look like this:

```
---
client:
  apiKey:
    id: "your_id_here"
    secret: "your_id_here"
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a link to the documentation, I'm actually trying to fit this into my config.yml that's generated when the bukkit plugin is initialised for the first time. I've slightly changed the layout to more closely match what you've provided. I'll give it a go and report back on what happens.